# Unit testing calling of stored procedures that return a value with Simple.Data

Tags: sql, unit-testing, stored-procedures, simple.data

I have the following stored procedure:

```
[dbo].[MyStoredProcedure] 
     @field1 int, @field2 int, @field3 nvarchar(5), @returnValue int output
```

I call it using Simple.Data and get the return value as follows:

```
 var result = db.MyStoredProcedure(intParam1, intParam2, stringParam3, new int());
 int returnValue = result.OutputValues["returnValue"];
```

I am trying to test the code above to ensure it gets `returnValue` from the `OutputValues` dictionary and handles the result of that correctly. To do so, I need to fake the stored procedure `MyStoredProcedure`.

I can see a good example of how to test stored procedures that add rows to the database in the Simple.Data documentation here:
[Simple.Data documentation](http://simplefx.org/simpledata/docs/pages/Test/Advanced.htm), but I cannot see how to return values from this function.

How do I simulate a stored procedure that takes a number of arguments (in my case `int`, `int`, `nvarchar`, `int`) and add my fake `returnValue` key (with corresponding `int` value) to the `OutputValues` dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

I generally try to avoid "unit testing" code that has permanent side-effects, but you *can* do it by setting up a transaction scope in your unit test:

```
    TransactionScope _trans;

    [TestInitialize()]
    public void Init()
    {
        _trans = new TransactionScope();  // start a new transaction
        base.InitializeTest();
    }

    [TestCleanup()]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        base.CleanupTest();
        _trans.Dispose();  // rollback the transaction
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void TransactedTest()
    {

        // set up test parameters

        var result = db.MyStoredProcedure(intParam1, intParam2, stringParam3, new int());
        int returnValue = result.OutputValues["returnValue"];

        // validate return value

    }
```